# Which version of Xcode has got iOS 13.7 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

Xcode 11.7 has iOS 13.6 simulator
Xcode 12.6 beta has 13.5 simulator

I wonder which version of Xcode I should download to get 13.7 simulator. Can someone please guide how to get iOS 13.7 simulator.

Thank you

Comment: Whoever down voted could you please explain the reason. Do not think that without doing a research I have posted this question. I have tried different versions of Xcode to get iOS 13.7 simulator and googled it to find any relevant info but no luck.

Comment: I'm not able to find 13.7 anywhere on Xcode-beta either, even after forcing refresh/manual add. SO community, this is not a bespoke question. 13.7 is already released to the public, we can't build against or own devices without it. Since this was a rushed covid build, i'm assuming internal teams failed to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode 11.7 has 13.7 simulators available.

Maybe it's not the selected one, but if you go to *Window* -> *Devices & Simulators* you should see a + on the bottom-left of that window. Clicking on that button you should be able to create new ones with iOS 13.7

[Adding a new iOS 13.7 simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvxZ9.png)

Comment: Thank you Pablo. I was looking at Xcode --> Preferences --> Components and it listed only 13.6 and gave me impression that 13.7 is not available.

Comment: I can't find it in Xcode 12. When I clicked + button on that screen,  I see that 13.5 version is top of the list. How can I find it?

Comment: if I'm not wrong you need two xcode versions 
1) 11.7 (iOS 13.7 simulator) 
2) 12 (for iOS 13.6 and iOS 14 simulator)
looks like apple is missing something or myself